# How do I parse a String inside a Drools condition?

Tags: java, parsing, drools

I am trying to define a simple rule with Drools 7 inside my Java application.

```
import com.ruleengine.domain.Alert;
import com.unifiedformat.UnifiedData;
import com.ruleengine.utils.DroolsUtils;
import java.util.*;

global com.ruleengine.domain.Alert alert;

dialect  "java"

rule "Calculate MAE - Scenario 1"
    when
        mae : DroolsUtils.stringToDouble(UnifiedData(getData().getValue()) > 0.1);
    then
        alert.setAlertMessage("The MAE is over 0.1! It is an anomaly!");
        alert.getNotifiedParties().add("SMS");
        alert.getNotifiedParties().add("EMAIL");
        alert.getNotifiedParties().add("FACEBOOK");
end
```

The UnifiedData.getData().getValue() returns a String object, something like 0.094342 (random case)

I am trying to parse this String into a Double since I want to compare the given String value to my threshold (0.1).

How can I do that with Drools? I am getting the following error with my code :

```
Unable to resolve ObjectType 'DroolsUtils.stringToDouble' : [Rule name='Calculate MAE - Scenario 1']
```

Comment: You have a parenthesis in the wrong place. It should be `DroolsUtils.stringToDouble(UnifiedData(getData().getValue())) > 0.1`

Comment: Dunno why you think you need your own conversion method either. There is already `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, unfortunately, it is still in error with your syntax. The message has changed to : [12,73]: [ERR 102] Line 12:73 mismatched input '>' in rule "Calculate MAE - Scenario 1"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package

Comment: Did you attempt to google it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785747/drools-decision-table-mismatched-input-in-rule

Comment: Yes, this article didn't resolve my problem!

Comment: When I use this syntax : when
     mae : UnifiedData(getData().getValue() > 0.1);   It gives me  : [Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found class java.lang.String and class java.lang.Double]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue with this code :

```
global Alert alert;

function Double getMae(UnifiedData unifiedData) { 
    return Double.valueOf(unifiedData.getData().getValue());
}

rule "Calculate MAE - Scenario 1"
    when
    mae : Double(getMae(UnifiedData(getData().getValue()) > 0.1);
    then
    alert.setAlertMessage("The MAE is over 0.1! It is an anomaly!");
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this:

Integer($mae: DroolsUtils.stringToDouble(UnifiedData(getData().getValue())) > 0.1 )

Comment: Unable to analyze expression 'DroolsUtils.stringToDouble(UnifiedData(getData().getValue()))' : [Rule name='Calculate MAE - Scenario 1']

Field Reader does not exist for declaration '$mae' in '$mae : DroolsUtils.stringToDouble(UnifiedData(getData().getValue()))' in the rule 'Calculate MAE - Scenario 1' : [Rule name='Calculate MAE - Scenario 1']